# Extracting POST request data from Express in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt

I have a fairly simple express server that is designed to take external client data and publish it via mqtt to a gateway. It works perfectly with a hardcoded variable but I can't figure out how to extract the actual data from the POST request, which is as follows (it prints to the console just fine):

```
const postData = app.post('/send-data', function (req, res) {
    console.log('connected', req.body);
    res.status(200).json(req.body)
});
```

I need to get the req.body data out of that and into the following code that publishes the data to the topic:

```
client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected!');
    client.publish('iot-2/type/wtlType/id/channel100/evt/event/fmt/json', publishData);
    client.end();
});
```

publishData will just be the stringified json response.

This is the create server code if that helps:

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(30002, () => {
    console.log('Listening')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question is about the logic of getting the `req.body` published by the client. If so, then something like this should work:

```js
let connected = false;

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected!');
    connected = true;
});

const postData = app.post('/send-data', function (req, res) {
    console.log('connected', req.body);
    res.status(200).json(req.body)
    client.publish('iot-2/type/wtlType/id/channel100/evt/event/fmt/json', JSON.stringify(req.body));
    client.end(); // are you sure you want this? can there not be more messages to broadcast?
});
```

Comment: That helped! I had to move some other code inside there as well, but that is what did it. Thanks!